# Unit conversion - Amazon API

Tags: api, amazon-product-api, unit-conversion

Amazon API returns strange dimensions. On the website, they have displayed:

```
Product Dimensions: 8.7 x 7.9 x 0.6 inches ; 1.8 ounces
Shipping Weight: 4 ounces
```

while the API returns:

```
[ItemDimensions] => Array
(
    [Height] => 59
    [Length] => 866
    [Weight] => 11
    [Width] => 787
)

[PackageDimensions] => Array
(
  [Height] => 50
  [Length] => 700
  [Weight] => 25
  [Width] => 200
)
```

I'm not sure what unit that is. I confirmed twice to make sure its the same product.

I need to convert it to `mm` and `grams`. `22cm or 220mm is 8.7 inches` so no clue whats `50` or `59` thats being returned. Same for weight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The product dimensions are in inches. Their display is achieved by dividing the stored values by 100 and adjusting the first place after the period.

```
Length -> stored as 866 - displayed as 8.7
Width  -> stored as 787 - displayed as 7.9
Height -> stored as 59  - displayed as 0.6
```

You can transfer this to the metric system by converting. 1 inch = 2.54 centimetres.

Take Length

```
866 / 100 = 8.66
8.66 * 2.54 = 21.9962 centimetres. 
Display as 22 cm, or 21.99 cm, etc...
```

The weight is stored in pounds, but displayed in ounces. 1 pound = 16 ounces, or 0.11 pounds = 1.76 ounces. 1.76 is adjusted to 1.8.

Since 1 pound = 453.592 grams, you can transfer by doing

```
0.11 * 453.492 = 49.89512 grams. 
Display as 49 g, or 49.9 g, etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

start with size dimensions:

```
59 = round(59/100, 1) = 0.6 inch
866 = 8.7
787 = 7.9
```

so, to get mm:

```
LengthInMM = LengthInInchFromResult * 25.4 / 100.0
```

now width:

```
11 = 1.8
25 = 4
```

HINT: 0.25 LBS = 4 ounces